# How does one justify this inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Let $f \in C[0,1]$ and let $\| f \|$ be the max of $f$ on $[0,1]$. Then we have
>
> $|f + g|(x) = |f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq |f|(x) + |g|(x)$.
>
> If $f$ has its max at $x_0$, then
>
> $\| f + g\| =|f + g|(x_0) = |f(x_0) + g(x_0)| \leq |f(x_0)| + |g(x_0)| \leq |f|(x_0) + |g|(x_0) \leq \| f \| + \| g \|$.

How do they first even justify $|f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq |f|(x) + |g|(x)$? Shouldn't it be $|f(x)| + |g(x)| = |f|(x) + |g|(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by definition, as $|f|$ is a function which maps $x$ to $|f(x)|$.

Comment: But why inequality? Shouldn't it be an equality?

Comment: Yes, so inequality is true (but less accurate).

Comment: But is it even an inequality in the first place? I need an example

Comment: @sizz Well, $1\leq 1$, yes?

Comment: Yes. I absolutely know what you are getting at. It just feels that step is kind of "unnatural". I am not quite sure how to explain it